# Designing entire webpages as SVG files

Tags: html, svg

### Disclaimer

I realize that given the absurdity of the title, this sounds like a troll. However, it's a genuine question. My background involves OpenGL / x86 assembly. I've recently started learning web programming. I really like SVG + CSS, and was wondering -- why do people not design entire webpages in SVG?

### Context

- SVG provides beautiful primitive: quadratic + cubic bezier curves; lines + filling -- all as vector graphics
- SVG provides text
- SVG provides affine transformations

### Questions

- Are there examples of people designing entire websites as a giant SVG file?
- If not, what the limitations?
- Are there performance hits when using SVG primitives as opposed to divs/tables?

Comment: SVG it's far more complex than HTML. Limitations are (were?) in browser implementations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible; for example you can embed HTML fragments in SVG documents in order to get things like hyperlinks.

However, there are some significant disadvantages, at least at present:

- Current web browsers treat SVGs as images, and may not present as good a UI to users. For example, I think Firefox doesn't allow the user to select text in SVG files.
- You lose separation of content and presentation. While SVG does use CSS, and you can in principle maintain the separation if you edit by hand, you are probably designing the layout together with the content. This has several drawbacks:

  - As a corollary, it's harder to adapt the resulting page to other formats. Particularly:
  - What's the behavior when the text size is changed? the document is printed? the window is resized? It's hard to design a complex drawing that supports **reflow** nicely (and if your drawing isn't complex, you may as well just use HTML+CSS).
  - **Screen reader** support: since order is not clear (below), screen readers may give incomprehensible, scrambled output. More basically, screen readers may assume the SVG is an image and not even try to read the text.
- SVG is exclusively based on XML, and hence requires pretty strict adherence to the rules. With (X)HTML, you have the option of using the plain HTML serialization. Then many of these rules are relaxed, and browsers are more robust if you feed them bogus input (as opposed to an `XML PARSING ERROR` if you have a single misplaced `>`).
- <del>Current search engines probably won't index your pages (they'll just treat them as monolithic images).</del> [*Never mind*](https://www.google.com/search?q=filetype%3Asvg)
- Order of the content is not clear. Tools like Inkscape don't need to care about the order elements are output in, as long as they are positioned correctly in the output and the z-order is correct. But if you're making a web page, this does matter, because screen readers don't know for sure which element is semantically first. This isn't an issue if you're only editing the SVG by hand, but the usual SVG tools may scramble your order. With HTML, it's generally clear.
- <del>It's difficult to implement fragment identifiers (`#id_of_some_element` at end of URL) well. The presentation program below uses them, but I think it depends on Javascript (bad for search engines and people with javascript disabled).</del> (I'm not sure about this one)
  *̶ ̶I̶t̶'̶s̶ ̶d̶i̶f̶f̶i̶c̶u̶l̶t̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶v̶e̶r̶t̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶t̶e̶x̶t̶ ̶(̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶s̶e̶a̶r̶c̶h̶ ̶e̶n̶g̶i̶n̶e̶s̶,̶ ̶s̶c̶r̶e̶e̶n̶ ̶r̶e̶a̶d̶e̶r̶s̶,̶ ̶c̶o̶p̶y̶-̶a̶n̶d̶-̶p̶a̶s̶t̶e̶,̶ ̶e̶t̶c̶.̶)̶,̶ ̶p̶a̶r̶t̶i̶c̶u̶l̶a̶r̶l̶y̶ ̶w̶h̶e̶n̶ ̶g̶e̶n̶e̶r̶a̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶g̶r̶a̶p̶h̶i̶c̶a̶l̶ ̶t̶o̶o̶l̶s̶.̶ ̶F̶o̶r̶ ̶e̶x̶a̶m̶p̶l̶e̶,̶ ̶h̶t̶t̶p̶:̶/̶/̶w̶w̶w̶.̶a̶f̶r̶o̶k̶a̶d̶a̶n̶s̶.̶c̶o̶m̶/̶P̶a̶g̶e̶_̶0̶1̶.̶s̶v̶g̶ ̶s̶h̶o̶w̶s̶ ̶u̶p̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶G̶o̶o̶g̶l̶e̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶`̶D̶A̶N̶S̶E̶ ̶E̶T̶ ̶M̶I̶S̶E̶ ̶E̶N̶ ̶F̶O̶R̶M̶E̶ ̶B̶I̶E̶N̶V̶E̶N̶U̶E̶ ̶D̶ ̶a̶ ̶n̶ ̶s̶ ̶e̶ ̶r̶ ̶p̶o̶ ̶u̶ ̶r̶ ̶c̶é̶ ̶l̶ ̶é̶b̶ ̶r̶ ̶e̶ ̶r̶ ̶l̶ ̶a̶ ̶v̶ ̶i̶e̶.̶ ̶E̶ ̶n̶ ̶v̶e̶ ̶l̶ ̶o̶p̶p̶ ̶é̶ ̶e̶ ̶d̶ ̶e̶ ̶t̶ ̶a̶ ̶m̶ ̶b̶ ̶o̶ ̶u̶r̶ ̶s̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶d̶o̶ ̶c̶ ̶i̶l̶ ̶e̶ ̶s̶ ̶e̶ ̶t̶ ̶i̶ ̶n̶ ̶c̶e̶ ̶s̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶n̶t̶s̶`̶.̶ ̶I̶n̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶t̶r̶a̶s̶t̶,̶ ̶e̶v̶e̶n̶ ̶c̶r̶a̶p̶p̶y̶ ̶W̶Y̶S̶I̶W̶Y̶G̶ ̶H̶T̶M̶L̶ ̶g̶e̶n̶e̶r̶a̶t̶o̶r̶s̶ ̶w̶o̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶s̶p̶l̶i̶t̶ ̶u̶p̶ ̶r̶u̶n̶s̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶t̶e̶x̶t̶ ̶l̶i̶k̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶.̶

Something to consider is that it is possible to embed SVG elements in XHTML and HTML 5, so you get some of the benefits without throwing off browsers/search engines.

## Existing usage

I've heard of its use for presentations (which are closer to drawings in some respects, so some of the above drawbacks don't apply):

- ["Jessyink is a JavaScript that can be incorporated into an Inkscape SVG image containing several layers. Each layer will be converted into one slide of a presentation."](http://code.google.com/p/jessyink/)
- [Another implemetation](http://adityab.github.com/Awwation/); [info](http://adityabhatt.wordpress.com/2012/04/06/writing-a-prezi-clone-with-html5-svg-and-javascript/) and [an example](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40496552/awwation-intro.svg)

Comment: "SVG is exclusively based on XML" is not quite true anymore. Svg can be included inline in html5, and follows the parsing rules specified there. It's even possible to have full svg files parsed as html these days, by adding a <!DOCTYPE html> at the top of the document (in most cases). Also google has been indexing svg files since 2010, see http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/08/google-now-indexes-svg.html.

Comment: I don't understand your last bulletpoint. You don't have to use javascript to do fragment identifiers, you can style it with CSS too, or use it for declarative animations, custom views of the document etc.

Comment: Clear + informative. I like the choice of nested bullet points (as opposed to programs of text.)

Comment: @ErikDahlström: I tried it and Firefox still barfs on XML errors even if you specify the HTML 5 doctype. Anyway, thanks for the corrections.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail testing a local svg file? you need to give the svg an *.html filename. On a web server you need to serve it with a 'text/html' mediatype.

Comment: http://www.afrokadans.com/Page_01.svg shows up as I'd expect, the content is just poorly formatted. It's essentially doing the equivalent of having a <div> per character, with repeating the style over and over once per character. There are plenty of examples of bad and inaccessible html out there too, but I wouldn't cite that as a reason for not using html...

Comment: "Order of the content is not clear. Tools like Inkscape don't need to care about the order elements are output in, as long as they are positioned correctly in the output." - the order you specify elements in is the order in which they get drawn (aka painter's algorithm), so it does matter quite a bit. All svg viewers follow that rule (as defined in the spec) or things would just not render correctly. I sadly agree with you that screenreader support for svg is poor to nonexistant, I hope that situation will improve.

Answer (score 1):

There is a platform designed specifically to create SVG-based websites: [Svija](https://svija.love) (disclaimer: it is my project).

The advantage of an SVG website is that you can literally do anything you want; you're not limited to rows of rectangles as you are with HTML.

The big issue is accessibility. Right now SVG text is crawled by Google but it can easily be out of order depending on the source document. Also semantic information that would normally be conveyed by HTML tags (H1 is more important than P) is nonexistant.

The main things to realize are that:

- you can use external fonts and images in an SVG file
- the width and height have to be specified correctly for Microsoft's browsers to display the SVG at the correct size
- if you combine different SVG files, conflicting ID's can cause CSS styles to be misapplied

The only program that I have found that can correctly link to images and fonts is Adobe Illustrator. There is a list of all the programs I have found that can create SVG files [here](https://svija.love/en/wtf#anchorSVG), with some information about which programs support which features.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are pages that rely heavily on SVG; using a Javascript library such as [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) is a common way to do it. [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/) is also worth a peek, although they chose [not to use SVG](http://paperjs.org/about/faq/#why-not-base-it-on-svg).

Answer (score -1):

You can indeed make entire web sites with SVG, I've been doing it for years. If you're willing to change how you look at designing pages (Think Cards) then it's just a matter of trial and error.

Comment: Please be careful with linking to your own content on different sites, you don't want to be a [spammer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). You should be including the majority of the content here, and use the link only as a reference.